# Over (partition by) troubles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anybody help with `Over` and `Partition` in my case statement

I'm trying to show `Y` for `Stvs.visitorID` with no `stse.SessionID`'s.

My 1st line works fine but Can cant get the 2nd line to work.

```
сase 
    when stse.datetimeselected < max(stse.datetimeselected) Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID) then 'N'
    when stse.SessionID is null Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID) then 'Y'
end as 'Y/N'
```

Answer (score 0):

Every line in `CASE` statement is evaluated separately. Therefore you do not need `OVER` clause at all.

Also consider using `ELSE 'Y'`, if you want to guarantee no `NULLs`.

My version:

```
Case 
when stse.datetimeselected < max(stse.datetimeselected) Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID) then 'N'
when stse.SessionID is null then 'Y'
END as 'Y/N'
```

Comment: This issue is with my 2nd line - 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword' 'Over'. This applies without the 1st line present so it's not related.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing.....

```
Case 
when stse.datetimeselected < max(stse.datetimeselected) Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID) then 'N'
when SUM(stse.SessionID) Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID)  is null then 'Y'
END as 'Y/N'
```

OR

```
Case 
when stse.datetimeselected < max(stse.datetimeselected) Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID) then 'N'
when COUNT(stse.SessionID) Over (partition by Stvs.visitorID)  = 0 then 'Y'
END as 'Y/N'
```

OR
    Use any of the `WINDOWING FUNCTIONS` instead of `COUNT(),SUM(),MAX()` FROM the follwing link
[Over Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but this won't this just give me a 'Y' next to the max session ID for each visitor? I need a 'Y' next to every visitor session where all sessions are NULL.  I also get - Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Rep_Recent_Searches2, Line 54 - appreciate your help.
Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator.